# Correct use for post_save signal?

Tags: python, django

My goal is: Whenever a new Note object is created, I want a row to be inserted in Review, which corresponds to Note via OnetoOne. Whenever Note is modified, I want to modify its corresponding entry in Review in some way.

I've currently implemented this (partially) using post_save signal. Although, this feels slightly hacky to me, and I'm wondering if there is a more appropriate method to doing this in Django? Or am I doing it correctly.

```py
class Review(models.Model):
    note = models.OneToOneField(Note, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    easiness = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3,max_digits=6)
    interval = models.IntegerField()
    repetitions = models.IntegerField()
    due_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=False)
    last_reviewed = models.DateField(auto_now=True,auto_now_add=False)

class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
# Create your models here.

@receiver(post_save, sender=Note)
def append_review(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    blank_review = {'easiness':0,'interval':0,'repetitions':0,'due_date':date.today(),'last_reviewed':date.today()}
    if created:
        Review.objects.create(note=instance, **blank_review)
    else:
        # modify existing entry instead...
```

Comment: why does it feel hacky to you?

Comment: I've understood signals to be ideally used when two apps need to communicate with each other and we want to avoid introducing circular dependencies. The two parts that I'm trying to link here exist in the same file, is it not an overkill to use this pattern here? Unless this is the correct way to do what I'm trying to do. I just want to know the best practice.

Comment: if you want it to fire anytime a model is saved regardless of method the right answer is to use signals ... if you want it only to fire when you do `Model.objects.create` you can overload the modelmanager create method, if you want to do it only when you do `MyNewModelInstance.save()` you can override save in your model ... but generally signals are exactly the way to do this